# How to propely wire from 320A meter/2x 200A disconnects 200 ft to panels at house?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I had posted on here before about my situation where i had already installed a single run of 3"conduit with a run of 500/500/350 in it but was having an issue with how to solit the service. Since then i had my PUD engineer come out and after a couple weeks the solution they came upwith was to install my 320 amp meter base and two 200 amp disconnects at the pole and then run an additional run of conduit to the house so my question now is do i need to pull the 500/500/350 and install 2 runs of 4 wire feeder to the panels at the house or is there a way to do this otherwise? What size wire do i need to properly install this? And how can i legally feed these two panels with this setup?

Answer (score 3):

### Can't run 400A on 500 kcmil

To start with, you can't run 400A on 500 kcmil aluminum. As we advised earlier, I hope the person who recommended that wire *is no longer on your team*.  Unfortunately you only have 3 choices:

- Down-breaker to 350A
- Pull 600 kcmil wire
- Pull dual 250 kcmil wires*
- You need a disconnect at the utility end, and a disconnect or distribution board at the house end.  Find such components that have a 90C thermal rating on their terminals. Unfortunately this will all be "industrial tier" stuff with prices to match.  However, you're into that anyway due to the need to have single 400A disconnects.

I would cost each option carefully, because of 90C equipment or a 350A breaker could blow right past the cost of new, appropriate wire.

Also, where is safety ground? You mention only 3 wires.

### You can't parallel, if that was your plan.

It sounds like your AHJ is giving you a waiver to go ahead and violate NEC 225.30.  That's a bit of a surprise, but not that much, since the NEC 2020 rules have had really weird and possibly unintended side-effects on 400A installations. AHJs get Sophie's Choice: force the consumer to spend thousands on industrial grade gear, or give waivers for important rules like 225.30.

So what the AHJ is saying is you can run dual 250 kcmil aluminum feeders - so that means 6x 250 kcmil wires for two 200A feeders, plus 1 safety ground wire that can be shared. **This scenario calls for you ripping out and selling your 500/300 kcmil wire**.

The AHJ is *not* authorizing paralleling!  You cannot merge the two 200A circuits onto the 500 kcmil wire even if it was allowed 400A, which it's not.

If you want to preserve the 500 kcmil wire (and I certainly would) -- you'll need to use a single 400A (or 350A) disconnect at the pole, and follow one of my points above.

* Why is 500 kcmil only 310 amps, yet 250 kcmil is 205 amps each?  With wire it's not just about cross section to carry current, it's also about surface area to allow heat to escape.  When you double the size of wires, the diameter and surface area only increase 40%, and that has a significant bearing on its ability to cool. Thus it affects the amp rating.

Comment: Thank you Harper, I believe that what the power company was suggesting was using the 500/500/350 as three of the six feeders and then adding a four wire feeder in the new run of conduit i just installed so as to avoid having to pull what is already in the ground if that makes sense?

Comment: That was my understanding however i wanted to double check before i bought any more wire or proceed any further. The inspector told me he would have been ok with the disconnect on the house if i could talk the power company into it but the solution they came up with after two weeks was either this or the 400 amp disconnect which i am still not finding reasonably priced so now that i have the two runs of conduit installed i just wanted to make sure i was sizing wire correctly and buying the appropriate amount if i ended up needing to replace what i currently have in ground to be legal

Comment: @Cstreight yes, keeping the 500 as one of the feeders makes sense.  No need to downsize.   Make sure the ground is sized for 400A not 200A.  The power company's advice was wrong because they were following their codebook NESC, not your codebook NEC.

Comment: What the power company had recommended was 4/0 4/0 2/0 i believe which it sounds like will not work but would six runs of 4/0 and one run of 2/0 be sufficient for the 320 amps or do i need to go with six runs of 250kcmil and one 3/0? And is it acceptable to have these run in two separate runs of conduit?

Comment: Ok so keep the 500/500/350 and add 250/250/250/3/0? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes your last comment is right @Cstreight.  The power company gets to use smaller wires.